# Switch to "Tracked to Dynamics 365" category from "Tracked to Dynamics 365 (Undeliverable) for multiple records simultaneously in Outlook

Tags: outlook, dynamics-365-sales

One of our clients has a lot of emails in 'Tracked to Dynamics 365 (Undeliverable)' in Outlook. Is there any way to move all of these emails into the 'Tracked to Dynamics 365' category in one go? I can not change the category in emails one after other because there are many emails. Please check the attached screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can develop a VBA macro for the desktop edition of Outlook or web-based Mail Add-ins if you need to get the functionality everywhere. See [Outlook add-ins overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-add-ins-overview) for more information.